# How to connect from localhost to a docker container running in a docker network

Tags: mysql, database, docker, docker-compose, devops

I have a docker container of mysql using docker compose like this:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db-server:
    container_name: database
    image: mysql:latest
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootTest
      MYSQL_USER: soumalya
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: userTest
    ports:
      - "3031:3306"
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql:ro
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  internal:
  driver: bridge
volumes:
  mysql:
```

I am connecting to localhost:3031 with correct password but it gives me this error:

```bash
Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

How can I fix this error. Other containers in the same `internal` network also can not connect to this database.

I'm giving the content of `Dockerfile` here:

```
ADD init.sql init.sql
```

I'm giving the content of init.sql here:

```
create database if not exists reviews;
create database if not exists users;
create database if not exists vendors;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on reviews.* to 'soumalya'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on users.* to 'soumalya'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on vendors.* to 'soumalya'@'%';
```

From the container log I can see the database is starting up and waiting for incoming connections in port 3306.

Comment: The error message indicates that your password or username is incorrect and I trust mysql in this over you.

Comment: No I'm copy pasting the password. I think its because of the host because the ip address shown after @ i.e., `172.19.0.1` is the container ip address and my local ip address is different may be mysql is restricting aceess because two hosts are different

Comment: If you have an existing database in your `mysql` volume, then the `MYSQL_*` environment variables aren't used. Then it just assumes that there are already users defined in the database and you need to use those. To have it use your environment variables, you need to delete the `mysql` volume and start the mysql container with an empty volume. It's the same with your init script. It's only run on database initialization.

Comment: Ok yes I remember I had changed the password of the databae without deleting the volume and the password here is a environment variable that is the reason may be thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

As @HansKillan Said as I had changed the password when the database was already existing the changed password got ignored and it was taking the old password. I had to manually change the password of my user by writing sql command using docker exec <container_name> ...sql command to change the password of the user. Then everything worked. In your case if your database does not contain much data then you can directly delete the volume and recreate the container to cut short